# How to apply css style for dynamic tr with td and input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I render the dynamically append the `tr` ,`td` and input tag with class name and I also write the `css` style for separate but it is not applied the dynamic `tr`.

Please find my code snippet.

```
 <table style="width:100%" class="tSheet">
            <tr class="t-header">
                <th class="t-head">sno</th>
                <th class="t-head">Description</th>
                <th class="t-head">Debit</th>
                <th class="t-head">Credit</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="t-content"><input type="text" class="t-input" /></td>
                <td class="t-content"><input type="text" class="t-input"  /></td>
                <td class="t-content"><input type="text" class="t-input" /></td>
                <td class="t-content"><input type="text" class="t-input" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**css style:**

```
.tSheet .t-head,.t-content  {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
.t-input{
border:0px none;
}
.t-input:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```

**my javaScript function:**

```
 $(function () {

    $('input').css("width", $('input').parent().width());
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        $("<tr><td class='t-content'><input class='t-content t-input/>'</td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input/>'</td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input/>'</td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input/>'</td></tr>").attr({ class: "a" }).appendTo('.tSheet')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `class` attribute closing is misplaced

1. Instead of using `attr()` use `addClass()` for adding class
2. For applying width use `css()` with callback, also do it after adding dynamic element or you can set css `width:100%` to input element
3. In your code class name attribute is not properly closed, change `<input class='t-content t-input/>'` to `<input class='t-content t-input'/>` and `<input class='t-input/>'` to `<input class='t-input'/>`

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $("<tr><td class='t-content'><input class='t-content t-input'/></td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input'/></td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input'/></td><td class='t-content'><input class='t-input'/></td></tr>").addClass("a").appendTo('.tSheet')
}
$('input').css("width", function() {
  return $(this).parent().width()
});
```

```css
.tSheet .t-head,
.t-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.t-input {
  border: 0px none;
}
.t-input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%" class="tSheet">
  <tr class="t-header">
    <th class="t-head">sno</th>
    <th class="t-head">Description</th>
    <th class="t-head">Debit</th>
    <th class="t-head">Credit</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="t-content">
      <input type="text" class="t-input" />
    </td>
    <td class="t-content">
      <input type="text" class="t-input" />
    </td>
    <td class="t-content">
      <input type="text" class="t-input" />
    </td>
    <td class="t-content">
      <input type="text" class="t-input" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @farookjm : glad to help :)